# DROP TABLE on a huge InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization

I have an innodb table with over 140 million rows taking 26GB. I would like to drop this table however this is taking way too long, probably days. How can I speed up this query?

processor: Intel® Xeon® E3-1220 4 Cores x 3.1 GHz (3.4 Turbo Boost) 
ram: 12 GB DDR3 ECC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can disable foreign key checks and unique checks:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE ...;
```

This has to work since a standard mysqldump embeds commands like these and a DROP TABLE before creating and reloading it. I have written about before

- `Jun 11, 2013` : [Speeding up mysqldump / reload](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44297/speeding-up-mysqldump-reload/44309#44309)
- `May 26, 2013` : [Is it possible to force drop of mysql tables with FK?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43053/is-it-possible-to-force-drop-of-mysql-tables-with-fk/43060#43060)
- `Jul 09, 2012` : [What can cause TRUNCATE TABLE to take a really long time?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20600/what-can-cause-truncate-table-to-take-a-really-long-time/20604#20604)

Further Suggestion : Based on [a post from mysqlperformanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/06/22/drop-table-and-stalls-lazy-drop-table-in-percona-server-and-the-new-fixes-in-mysql/), you should get Percona Server or upgrade to the latest version of MySQL (5.5.23 has improvements to `DROP TABLE`, so 5.6 should have those improvements as well).

As for your current `DROP TABLE`, you must let it ride for maintain InnoDB's stability.

Comment: wow I wish I had more reputation to upvote your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for accepting, and Welcome to the DBA StackExchange.